# uitviewcontroller with uitableview and custom uitableviewcells with uitextfields scroll up/down with keyboard

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uiscrollview, uikeyboard

I am having some difficulty figuring out the best way to get my uitextfields to not be hidden when the keyboard popsup.  Right now i have a UIView that contains a uitableview subview and button.

*The tableview that is inside the uiview is actually a uiviewcontroller with a programatically created tableivew, so it is not controlled by a uitableviewcontroller.

I have done research and i think i would need a scrollview then add the view to the scrollview and work on some scrolling when a specific textfield is selected and is hidden with the keyboard up scroll it up.

Is this a good approach ?

UPDATE:

I have two seperate Viewcontrollers.  For-example let say MainViewcontroller and SecondViewcontroller.  The secondviewcontroller has a uitableview in it.  The cells inside of the tableview have textboxes which store user information(like a form).  Then what i did was created an object of secondviewcontroller inside of mainviewcontroller.  I did this becuause i need to have a "Next Button" at the bottom of the view.  When I select a field where it would be located underneith the keyboard when it pops up i would like to have it scroll up and when closed it will go down.  I had to use an object of uitableview because the Mainviewcontroller class would be way to big.(Please correct me if i am wrong).  Thanks for the reply.

Here is a screenshot of what i am trying to do...
FUll UIView: http://postimage.org/image/puzdwpj3t/
With Keyboard open: http://postimage.org/image/g5nkwzwpd/

//Here is some code:
1. The first class here is for instance SecondViewcontroller.
2. The second section of code is for instance the mainviewcontroller, which creates an object of secondviewcontroller.

1. The below uiviewcontroller will create a table with 3 sections.  Each cell has a textfield(except the middle, it is a button which pulls up a uipickerview).  This is not a full class i only took the areas where the table is created.

   ```
   -(void)viewDidLoad{
   [super viewDidLoad];




   //    scrollview = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 500)];
   //    scrollview.pagingEnabled = YES;
   //    
   //    //[scrollview addSubview:self.view];
   //    [self.view addSubview:scrollview];



   table.scrollEnabled = YES;
   dataArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
   titleLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 290, 30)];

   //dropper
   titleField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 2, 300, 30)];
   titleField.layer.cornerRadius = 8;
   titleField.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

   NSArray *firstItemsArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"1",@"2", nil];

   NSDictionary *firstItemsArrayDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:firstItemsArray forKey:@"data"];
   [dataArray addObject:firstItemsArrayDict];


   //Second section dat
   NSArray *secondItemsArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"1", nil];
   NSDictionary *secondItemsArrayDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:secondItemsArray forKey:@"data"];
   [dataArray addObject:secondItemsArrayDict];


   NSArray *thirdItemsArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"3", nil];
   NSDictionary *thirdItemsArrayDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:thirdItemsArray forKey:@"data"];
   [dataArray addObject:thirdItemsArrayDict];

   NSLog(@"the dataArray%@",dataArray);


   if([self connectedToNetwork]){

   dispatch_async(kBgQueue, ^{

   //build the url of strings
   FULLURL = [SERVERNAME stringByAppendingFormat:TitleLink];
   //create the url
   NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:FULLURL];
   //NSLog(@"here title url%@",url);

   //get the data from the url
   NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: url];
   //NSLog(@"here%@",data);

   //get the data from the url
   [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(fetchedData:) withObject:data waitUntilDone:YES];
   // NSLog(@"titleid:%@",TITLEID);
   // NSLog(@"title categories:%@",titlecategories);

   });

   [table setBounces:NO];


   }else{


   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^ {
   UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
         initWithTitle: @"Please Check your internet connection"
         message:@"Enable your internet connection"
         delegate: nil
         cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
         otherButtonTitles:nil];
   [alert show];
   });
   }

   }

   -(NSInteger) numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
   {
   return [dataArray count];
   }


   -(NSInteger) tableView:(UITableView *)table numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
   {
   //Number of rows it should expect should be based on the section
   NSDictionary *dictionary = [dataArray objectAtIndex:section];
   NSArray *array = [dictionary objectForKey:@"data"];
   return [array count];

   }

   - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

   if(indexPath.section == 1){
   cell.backgroundColor =[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"longdropper300.png"]];

   }
   else{
   cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
   }
   }


   - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


   textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15, 10, 290, 30)];


   static NSString *cellValue = @"Cell";
   UITableViewCell *cell =nil;

   if (cell == nil) {
   cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellValue];
   }
   cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray;

   if ([indexPath section] == 0) {

   //cellValue=[items objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
   cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
   cell.selectionStyle= UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
   //textField.tag = 1;
   textField.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
   textField.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];

   if(indexPath.section == 0){
   //textfield for email
   if ([indexPath row] == 0) {
   textField.tag = 1;
   textField.text = EMAIL;
   textField.textColor= [UIColor blackColor];
   textField.placeholder = @"Email: example@gmail.com";
   textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeEmailAddress;
   textField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyNext;

   }
   //textfield for phone number
   else {
   textField.tag = 2;
   if ([PHONENUMBER isEqual: [NSNull null]] && PHONENUMBER == nil && PHONENUMBER == NULL && [PHONENUMBER isEqual: @""]){
   NSLog(@"phone is empty%@",PHONENUMBER);
   //[PHONENUMBER isEqual:@"frank"];

   }else{
   NSLog(@"phone is not empty%@",PHONENUMBER);
   textField.text = PHONENUMBER;
   }

   textField.placeholder = @"Phone: xxx-xxx-xxxx";
   textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
   textField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
   textField.secureTextEntry = NO;
   }
   textField.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
   textField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo; // no auto correction support
   textField.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone; // no auto capitalization support
   textField.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
   textField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeNever; // no clear 'x' button to the right
   [textField setEnabled: YES];
   textField.delegate = self;
   [cell addSubview:textField];

   }
   }
   if(indexPath.section == 1){

   [titleField setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
   titleField.tag = 3;
   titleField.placeholder = @"Select Contact Title";
   titleField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyNext;

   //titleField == textField.tag = 3;
   if ([TITLENAME isEqual: [NSNull null]]){
   NSLog(@"titlename is empty%@",TITLENAME);

   }else{
   NSLog(@"titlename is not empty%@",TITLENAME);
   titleField.text = TITLENAME;
   }


   titleField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
   titleField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
   titleField.secureTextEntry = NO;
   titleField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo; // no auto correction support
   titleField.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone; // no auto capitalization support
   titleField.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
   titleField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeNever; // no clear 'x' button to the right
   [titleField setEnabled: NO];
   titleField.delegate = self;

   [cell addSubview:titleField];


   NSLog(@"here is the titlename%@",TITLENAME);

   }

   if(indexPath.section == 2){

   if ([indexPath row] == 0) {

   textField.tag = 4;
   textField.placeholder = @"First Name";
   cell.selectionStyle= UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

   if ([FIRSTNAME isEqual: [NSNull null]]){
   NSLog(@"firstname is empty%@",FIRSTNAME);
   textField.text = @"";

   }else{

   textField.text = FIRSTNAME;

   }

   textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeEmailAddress;
   textField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyNext;
   }

   if([indexPath row] == 1){
   textField.tag = 5;
   textField.placeholder = @"Last Name";


   if ([LASTNAME isEqual: [NSNull null]]){
   NSLog(@"lastname is empty%@",LASTNAME);
   textField.text = @"";

   }else{
   textField.text = LASTNAME;


   }
   textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
   textField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyNext;
   //textField.secureTextEntry = NO;

   }

   if([indexPath row] == 2){

   textField.tag = 6;
   textField.placeholder = @"Company";

   if ([COMPANY isEqual: [NSNull null]]){
   NSLog(@"company is empty%@",COMPANY);
   textField.text = @"";
   }
   else{
   textField.text = COMPANY;
   }

   textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
   textField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
   textField.secureTextEntry = NO;


   }

   //]textField.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
   textField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo; // no auto correction support
   textField.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone; // no auto capitalization support
   textField.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
   textField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeNever; // no clear 'x' button to the right
   [textField setEnabled: YES];
   textField.delegate = self;
   [cell addSubview:textField];

   }

   return cell;
   }

   //Change the Height of title cell drop down
   -(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
   {
   if (indexPath.section == 1) {
   if (indexPath.row == 0) {
   return 30;
   }
   }
   return 45;
   }



   - (BOOL)textFieldShouldEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField{

   if(([textField tag] == 1)){

   NSString *emailRegEx = @"[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}";
   NSPredicate *emailTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegEx];
   //Valid email address

   if ([emailTest evaluateWithObject:textField.text] == YES)
   {

   EMAIL = [textField.text copy];
   NSLog(@"here is the email%@",EMAIL);
   }
   else
   {

   UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]

                 initWithTitle: @"Bad Email"
                 message: @"Please Re-enter the email address with a valid email"
                 delegate: nil
                 cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                 otherButtonTitles:nil];
   [alert show];
   textField.text =  nil;
   NSLog(@"email not in proper format");
   }

   }

   if(([textField tag] == 2)){

   NSString *phoneRegex = @"[235689][0-9]{6}([0-9]{3})?";
   NSPredicate *phoneTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", phoneRegex];
   //valid email address

   if ([phoneTest evaluateWithObject:textField.text] == YES)
   {

   PHONENUMBER = [textField.text copy];
   NSLog(@"here is the phone number %@",PHONENUMBER);
   }
   else
   {
   NSLog(@"Phone Number Invalid");
   UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                 initWithTitle: @"xxx-xxx-xxxx"
                 message: @"Please enter a valid phone number"
                 delegate: nil
                 cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                 otherButtonTitles:nil];
   [alert show];
   textField.text =  nil;
   }
   }

   if(([textField tag] == 4)){


   FIRSTNAME = [textField.text copy];
   NSLog(@"here is the firstName%@",FIRSTNAME);
   }
   if(([textField tag] == 5)){


   LASTNAME = [textField.text copy];
   NSLog(@"here is the Last Name%@",LASTNAME);
   }

   if(([textField tag] == 6)){

   COMPANY = [textField.text copy];
   NSLog(@"here is the Company%@",COMPANY);
   }




   return YES;
   }

   -(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField*)textField;
   {
   NSInteger nextTag = textField.tag + 1;
   // Try to find next responder
   UIResponder* nextResponder = [textField.superview viewWithTag:nextTag];
   if (nextResponder) {

   // Found next responder, so set it.
   [nextResponder becomeFirstResponder];
   } else {
   // Not found, so remove keyboard.
   [textField resignFirstResponder];
   }
   return NO; // We do not want UITextField to insert line-breaks.
   }
   ```
2. Main View Controller
       - (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
       {
       self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
       if (self) {
       // Custom initialization
       }
       return self;
       }

   ```
   - (void)addMyButton{    // Method for creating button, with background image and other properties

   loginButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
   loginButton.frame = CGRectMake(10.0,130.0, 300.0, 40.0);
   [loginButton setTitle:@"Login" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
   loginButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
   [loginButton setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal ];
   UIImage *buttonImageNormal = [UIImage imageNamed:@"blueButton.png"];
   UIImage *strechableButtonImageNormal = [buttonImageNormal stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:12 topCapHeight:0];
   [loginButton setBackgroundImage:strechableButtonImageNormal forState:UIControlStateNormal];
   UIImage *buttonImagePressed = [UIImage imageNamed:@"whiteButton.png"];
   UIImage *strechableButtonImagePressed = [buttonImagePressed stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:12 topCapHeight:0];
   [loginButton setBackgroundImage:strechableButtonImagePressed forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
   [self.view addSubview:loginButton];
   [loginButton addTarget: self
   action: @selector(loginButtonClicked:)
   forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
   }

   //Change the View and send the information to the servlet once login is clicked.
   - (void)loginButtonClicked: (id)sender{

   loginButton.enabled = NO;
   activityIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 60, 20, 20)];
   UIBarButtonItem * barButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:activityIndicator];
   [self navigationItem].rightBarButtonItem = barButton;
   [activityIndicator startAnimating];

   [passwordTF resignFirstResponder];



   //start new thread
   //dispatch_async(kBgQueue, ^{
   NSLog(@"Username:%@",USERNAME);
   NSLog(@"Password:%@",PASSWORD);
   NSLog(@"COMPANYID: %@", COMPANYID);
   //NSLog(@"LOGINID: %@", LOGINID);

   if((USERNAME == NULL) || (USERNAME == nil) || ([USERNAME isEqualToString:@""])){
   //NSLog(@"null password or usernaem");
   UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
             initWithTitle: @"Username or password not found"
             message:@"please try again"
             delegate: nil
             cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
             otherButtonTitles:nil];
   [alert show];
   [activityIndicator stopAnimating];

   // MangoLoginViewController *SenderInfoViews = [[MangoLoginViewController alloc] init];
   // [self.navigationController pushViewController:SenderInfoViews animated:NO];

   }else if((PASSWORD == NULL) || (PASSWORD == nil) || ([PASSWORD isEqualToString:@""])){
   //NSLog(@"null password or usernaem");

   UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
             initWithTitle: @"Username or password not found"
             message:@"please try again"
             delegate: nil
             cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
             otherButtonTitles:nil];
   [alert show];
   [activityIndicator stopAnimating];

   // MangoLoginViewController *SenderInfoViews = [[MangoLoginViewController alloc] init];
   // [self.navigationController pushViewController:SenderInfoViews animated:NO];

   }else{
   //NSLog(@"all good");

   NSLog(@"Login button clicked, load the next view and check for password");
   NSLog(@"full the url%@",FULLURL);
   //build the url of strings
   FULLURL = ******


   if([self connectedToNetwork])

   {
   dispatch_queue_t downloadQueue = dispatch_queue_create("data loader", NULL);

   dispatch_async(downloadQueue, ^{

   //create the url
   NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:FULLURL];
   NSLog(@"here%@",url);

   //get the data from the url
   NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: url];
   NSLog(@"here%@",data);

   NSLog(@"here that data%@",data);

   if(data != nil){
   //
   //get the data from the url

   [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(fetchedData:) withObject:data waitUntilDone:YES];
   //
   NSLog(@"hello Username:%@",USERNAME);
   NSLog(@"Password:%@",PASSWORD);
   NSLog(@"h4llo COMPANYID: %@", COMPANYID);
   NSLog(@"LOGINID: %@", LOGINID);

   //
   //       // [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(checkLogin:) withObject:LOGINID waitUntilDone:YES];
   //
   //
   @try {
   //NSLog(@"before loginddd %@",LOGINID);
   if(COMPANYID != 0){

       NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
       [prefs setObject:USERNAME forKey:@"UserName"];
       [prefs setObject:@"Pass" forKey:@"Pass"];
       // This is suggested to synch prefs, but is not needed
       [prefs synchronize];

       NSLog(@"here is the login identiy%@",LOGINID);
       MangoContactSelection *SenderInfoViews = [[MangoContactSelection alloc] init];
       [self.navigationController pushViewController:SenderInfoViews animated:NO];



   }
   else{
       dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^ {
       UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                             initWithTitle: @"bad NAME"
                             message:@"GOO"
                             delegate: nil
                             cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                             otherButtonTitles:nil];
       [alert show];

   //                        [self.view setNeedsDisplay];
       [self.view reloadInputViews];
       MangoLoginViewController *SenderInfoViews = [[MangoLoginViewController alloc] init];
       [self.navigationController pushViewController:SenderInfoViews animated:NO];
           [activityIndicator stopAnimating];
       });
   }
   }
   @catch (NSException * e) {
   NSLog(@"Exception: %@", e);
   UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                         initWithTitle: @"Login Failed"
                         message:@"Bad"
                         delegate: nil
                         cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                         otherButtonTitles:nil];
   [alert show];
   //[activityIndicator stopAnimating];
   }

   // if the data is nil do this
   }else{
   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^ {
   UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                     initWithTitle: @"No Internet!"
                     message:@"Please Check your internet Connection"
                     delegate: nil
                     cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                     otherButtonTitles:nil];
   [alert show];
   [self.view setNeedsDisplay];
   MangoLoginViewController *SenderInfoViews = [[MangoLoginViewController alloc] init];
   [self.navigationController pushViewController:SenderInfoViews animated:NO];
   });
   }

   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^ {

   //UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];

   //[table reloadData];
   //[actIndicator stopAnimating];
   [self.view reloadInputViews];
   [activityIndicator stopAnimating];

   // sender because that's the element that called us by clicking refresh

   });

   });


   }else{

   UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                 initWithTitle: @"No Internet!"
                 message:@"Please Check your internet Connection"
                 delegate: nil
                 cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                 otherButtonTitles:nil];
   [alert show];
   [self.view setNeedsDisplay];
   MangoLoginViewController *SenderInfoViews = [[MangoLoginViewController alloc] init];
   [self.navigationController pushViewController:SenderInfoViews animated:NO];
   }
   }
   [self.view reloadInputViews];
   }//login

   -(void)gobacktoContactCreate{
   MangoContactSelection *gobackhome = [[MangoContactSelection alloc]init];
   [self.navigationController pushViewController:gobackhome animated:YES];

   }

   - (void)viewDidLoad
   {

   [super viewDidLoad];
   //self.view setBackgroundColor:([UIColor blackColor]);
   NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
   NSString *userName = [prefs stringForKey:@"UserName"];
   //NSString *pass = [prefs stringForKey:@"Pass"];

   //navigation bar
   self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
   [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden: NO animated:NO];
   self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;

   self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:@selector(gobacktoContactCreate)];

   self.navigationItem.title=@"Login";

   //User name text field................
   usernameTF = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 25, 300, 40)];
   usernameTF.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
   usernameTF.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15];
   usernameTF.placeholder = @"Username";
   usernameTF.text = userName;
   usernameTF.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
   usernameTF.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
   usernameTF.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyNext;
   usernameTF.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
   usernameTF.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;



   //User name text field................
   passwordTF = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 75, 300, 40)];
   passwordTF.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
   passwordTF.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15];
   passwordTF.placeholder = @"Password";
   passwordTF.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
   passwordTF.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
   passwordTF.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
   passwordTF.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
   passwordTF.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;
   passwordTF.secureTextEntry = YES;

   //create the clickable labels
   //register link
   registerLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(150,170, 150, 20)];
   registerLabel.text = @"Request an account";
   registerLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];
   registerLabel.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
   registerLabel.textColor = [UIColor blueColor];
   UITapGestureRecognizer *gr = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(requestRegistration:)];
   [registerLabel addGestureRecognizer:gr];
   gr.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
   gr.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;

   //create the label for
   registerText = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(60,170, 90, 20)];
   registerText.text = @"New to *******?";
   registerText.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];

   //    //forgot password link
   //    forgotPassword = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(210,190, 150, 20)];
   //    forgotPassword.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];
   //    forgotPassword.textColor = [UIColor blueColor];
   //    forgotPassword.text = @"Forgot Password?";
   //    forgotPassword.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
   //    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRec = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(requestForgottenPassword:)];
   //    [registerLabel addGestureRecognizer:tapRec];
   //    tapRec.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
   //    tapRec.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;

   [self.view addSubview:passwordTF];
   [self.view addSubview:usernameTF];
   [self.view addSubview:registerLabel];
   [self.view addSubview:registerText];

   //    [self.view addSubview:forgotPassword];

   [self addMyButton];

   usernameTF.delegate = self;
   passwordTF.delegate = self;

   }

   -(void)requestRegistration:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gr{

   //for registration
   NSLog(@"request registration link clicked");

   }


   -(void)requestNewPassword:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)tapRec{

   //for registration
   NSLog(@"request password link clicked");
   }



   //Grabs the Json from the servlet and then parses it for the username and password.

   - (void)fetchedData:(NSData *)responseData {
   //parse out the json data

   NSError* error;
   NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData //1
                                        options:kNilOptions
                                          error:&error];

   //NSLog(@"here is the login info from json: %@", json);
   // NSString *FALSELOGIN;


   COMPANYID = [json valueForKey:@"companyid"];
   NSLog(@"COMPANY ID: %@", COMPANYID);

   // LOGINID = [json valueForKey:@"login"];
   // NSLog(@"LOGIN ID: %@", LOGINID);

   }

   - (BOOL)textFieldShouldEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField{

   if((textField = usernameTF)){
   USERNAME = [textField.text copy];
   //NSLog(@"here is the string for username;%@", USERNAME);
   }

   if((textField = passwordTF)){
   PASSWORD = [textField.text copy];

   //NSLog(@"here is the password guy %@",PASSWORD);

   }

   return YES;
   }




   -(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
   {
   if (textField == usernameTF) {
   [passwordTF becomeFirstResponder];
   }
   else{
   [passwordTF resignFirstResponder];
   }
   return YES;
   }


   //- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
   //{
   //    [passwordTF resignFirstResponder];
   //
   //}

   - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
   {
   [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
   // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
   }

   @end
   ```

Comment: Please add some code.

Comment: I have added some code thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dhaval, I beleive your solution would work, but I ended up finding exactly what i was looking for here:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=qSvDWnasJ9I

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have added Tableview inside view of UIViewController. right?

In which view you have added UITextview.? View of UIViewController ??

You can add UITextView in UIView and by applying animation just change frame of UITextView.

Ex.

// Take View UP....

```
[UIView animationWithDuration:secs delay:0.0 option:option animation:^{

    CGRect frame = textview.frame;
    frame.origin.y = 10; // Change Y position of frame.
    textview.frame = frame;

}
completion:nil];
```

// Take View down

```
[UIView animationWithDuration:secs delay:0.0 option:option animation:^{

    CGRect frame = textview.frame;
    frame.origin.y = 100; // Change Y position of frame.
    textview.frame = frame;

}
completion:nil];
```

No need to take UIScrollView.